# Unable to connect in Management Studio Express of SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to connect to my local machine name as "Server Name", and giving windows authentication, but its throwing some error:-

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

Please note previously it was connecting all well some few months back, but now it throws error. I tried lot of alternatives provided around the web, but nothing worked. 
Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

If the service is running on your local machine, try connecting with "LocalHost" as the server name.
Also, did you check that the service is running?

Comment: "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" is in Automatic mode and started. "SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)" is set to Automatic, but I can't manually start it as it is throwing some error:- "The service didn't respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."
"LocalHost" didn't work.

Comment: Can you connect with a SQL login?  Maybe you didn't give your windows login the right permissions.

Comment: I can't remember SQL login. : (

Comment: There is always the SA login - do you remember the PW you gave it?

Comment: See if you can add a new sysadmin login like this: http://sqlserver-help.com/2012/02/08/help-i-lost-sa-password-and-no-one-has-system-administrator-sysadmin-permission-what-should-i-do/

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this to happen:

1. Check if your SQL is up and running
2. Check there is no firewall messing around
3. Check on the configuration manager if sql services is up
4. Check if TCP/IP is active on the configuration manager

Sometimes, I know is weird, but his error shows up if you haven't configured your server for mixed security (both windows and SQL Server). Try connecting with a windows user with SA permissions and activate SQL authentication as well.

To do this, open SQL Server manager and connect with the SA user, right click on the server properties, check the "Security" tab for "SQL Sever and windows authentication mode"

Check this blog post that will lead you from some of the points I told you.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/